# Synching MSSQL and mysql database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have two databases on two servers. One is MSSQL and the other one is mysql . There are two similar table in two databses. How do I automatically update the mysql one the moment I update the MSSQL one?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SQL Server CLR integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), create a trigger to update MySQL. There is a [Sync Data from SQL Server to MySQL example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216352/An-alternative-to-Sync-Data-from-SQL-Server-to-MyS) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a `Linked Server`

Run this script as a member of `sysadmin` group:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'MYSQL'
    , @srvproduct=N'MySQL'
    , @provider=N'MSDASQL'
    , @datasrc=N'MySQL'
    , @provstr=N'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=Server;PORT=3306;DATABASE=DBName; USER=user;PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;'
    , @catalog=N'DatabaseName'

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSQL', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = N'MYSQL'
    , @locallogin = NULL 
    , @useself = N'False'
    , @rmtuser = N'user'
    , @rmtpassword = N'password'
GO
```

then use triggers on INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE to reflect your changes on the other server.

for example, INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ti_MyTable
   ON  dbo.MyTable
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO MySql.Database..MyTable (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM Inserted
END
GO
```